# is there a way to add a x-axis below the primary x-axis in r?

Tags: r

I have a scatterplot depicting # of snails on the y-axis, and distance on the x-axis. I would like to include a secondary x-axis depicting Age located below the primary x-axis. These values, however, would be arbitrary. I don't want it to affect where the data points themselves end up. I hope this makes sense!

Here is an example of my current graph. I tried to adjust the margins so that there would be more space in the bottom one to accommodate the additional graduated axis.

[image: Graph]

[Here is my sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wQfj.png):

```
data <- structure(list(Age = c("1", "5", "10", "15", "20"), Distance = c("10", 
"20", "30", "40", "50"), Snails = c("7", "3", "12", "24", "27"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: hi @ruizhouston the chart image is blank. could you please reupload it. also if you can provide us sample data it will be great.

Comment: @HarshalGajare hello thank you for your response! I'm new to the community, what would be the best way to provide sample data? I can add a screenshot/image of it to the original question

Comment: you can get dput(head(df, 10) where df is your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with base R:

```
par(mar = c(7,5,3,2))
plot(Snails ~ Distance, data, xlim = c(0, 50), ylim = c(0,30),
     pch = 0, xlab = "", ylab = "Snails")
lines(Snails ~ Distance, data)
axis(1, at = c(0,10,20,30,40,50), labels=c(0,data$Age),
     line=2.5, col="blue", col.ticks="blue", col.axis="blue")
mtext("Distance (m)", 1, line=1, at=-6)
mtext("Age", 1, line=2.5, at=-6, col = "blue")
```

[image]